# Change url in my magento site

Tags: php, magento

How i can change url in my magneto site ?

I have link:

`/configure-your-plan/index/samePage`;

where `configure-your-plan` is front name my module and `samePage` is my method in index controller.

How i can change my link in this type of link: `/configure-your-plan/index/same_page` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can go and edit the config.xml of the module and there you can change it under the tag frontname.